# IniFiles in .NET

Tags: .net

What is the best way to read and write .INI files in .NET?  It looks like I could write my own parser or use native Windows API calls but neither of those options are very appealing.  Are there other options?

Comment: Why are you using INI files? Unless you have legacy INI files to deal with, you should use the new Settings/ConfigurationManager code to store/retrieve your settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Nini in the past:

[Nini](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nini/)

Comment: +1 for Nini - Even though the project seems to have died down, what's already available is very usable.

Answer (score 1):

.Net uses an xml-based system for it's own configuration information.  If you're looking to do this for configuration for your own program you should really go that route.

Because of this, Microsoft hasn't really seen the need to provide a built-in *.ini parser. If you need to support files for legacy apps it means you're down to reading the files from disk and parsing them manually.  There are a number of different third-party options out there you could use to make this easier, but google will do a better job recommending one than I could.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Nini](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nini/) in the past with success, the page seems to be broken at the moment however, soourceforge are having issues and that might be the cause.

EDIT: Beaten by 45 seconds, typical!

Answer (score 0):

here is a technique for using reflection and binding to an ini file:

http://dvuyka.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!305B02907E9BE19A!174.entry?wa=wsignin1.0&sa=372854585